# Ajax +wordpress onClick link redirect to new page and create html content

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

i have two pages in my wordpress plugin

- index.php
- charts.php

in index.php i have some content and some link..

```
 <a onclick="show_trend()" >Trend</a>
```

while clicking this link  ,i have an ajax function to create content in charts.php(i dont know if it is correct way)

```
function show_trend() {
 var data ="action=render_admin_charts_page";
   jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {

                      alert(data);
                     //here i want to create html content

                    }
                });

}
```

andfollowing  is my php function and hook

```
function render_admin_charts_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="chart">

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
     die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_render_admin_charts_page', 'render_admin_charts_page' );
```

now i am getting `0` as alert  .

Answer (score 0):

try to json encode the html

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_render_admin_charts_page', 'render_admin_charts_page' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_render_admin_charts_page', 'render_admin_charts_page' );
function render_admin_charts_page() {

    $something = '<div class="wrap">
        <div class="chart">

        </div>
    </div>
    ';
    $output = array( $something);
    $output = json_encode($output);
    echo $output;
    die();  
}
```

For more details check http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins